# Discord.py | Delete empty voice channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for my discord server and I'm having trouble. What I want is when the last person leaves a voice channel (it had been generated by the bot), I want to delete the voice channel.

I've also thought about testing for any empty voice channels and deleting them, but I'm not sure how to do either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_#discord.on_voice_state_update) event to test when members leave the voice channel, check if it is empty, and then [VoiceChannel.delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_#discord.VoiceChannel.delete)

Comment: how do I check if it's empty

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_#discord.VoiceChannel.members